# success/error message keeps disappearing while submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an application `(editsessionadmin.php)` where the user displays their assessment's name, date and time in the relevant text inputs. Now when the user submits, it will display a confirmation, when the user confirms, then by using ajax, it navigates to the `updatedatetime.php` where it will update the assessment's time and date in the database and display the success or error message at the top of the `editsessionadmin.php` page.

But I have a small problems.

Problem : Using a div tag, I am able to retrieve the error or success message after the update from the `updatedatetime.php` script and display it in the `editsessionadmin.php` script by using this jquery code `$("#targetdiv").html(data)`. Problem is though is that when the user submits the form, it displays the message and then the message disappears after form is submitted. I want the message to be displayed at the top of the `editsessionadmin.php` page and not disappear. Why is it disappearing?

Below is the code for editsessionadmin.php

```
        <script>

    function submitform() {    

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/updatedatetime.php",
        data: $('#updateForm').serialize(),
        success: function(html){
            $("#targetdiv").html(html);
        }
     });        
}

         function showConfirm(){

          var examInput = document.getElementById('newAssessment').value;
          var dateInput = document.getElementById('newDate').value;
          var timeInput = document.getElementById('newTime').value;

          if (editvalidation()) {

         var confirmMsg=confirm("Are you sure you want to update the following:" + "\n" + "Exam: " + examInput +  "\n" + "Date: " + dateInput + "\n" + "Time: " + timeInput);

         if (confirmMsg==true)
         {
         submitform();   
     }
  }
} 

$('body').on('click', '#updateSubmit', showConfirm); 

            </script>   

        <h1>EDIT AN ASSESSMENT'S DATE/START TIME</h1>   

        <p>You can edit assessment's Date and Start time on this page. Only active assessments can be editted.</p>

        <div id="targetdiv"></div>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validation();">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Course: INFO101</th>
        <th>Module: CHI2513</th>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <p><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Course and Module" name="moduleSubmit" /></p>

        </form>


        ....


        <?php
        $editsession = "<form id='updateForm'>

        <p><strong>New Assessment's Date/Start Time:</strong></p>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Assessment:</th>
        <td><input type='text' id='newAssessment' name='Assessmentnew' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Date:</th> 
        <td><input type='text' id='newDate' name='Datenew' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Start Time:</th> 
        <td><input type='text' id='newTime' name='Timenew' readonly='readonly' value=''/><span class='timepicker_button_trigger'><img src='Images/clock.gif' alt='Choose Time' /></span> </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <div id='datetimeAlert'></div>

<button id='updateSubmit'>Update Date/Start Time</button>


        </form>
        ";

        echo $editsession;


        }

        ?>
```

Below is the code for updatedatetime.php:

```
<?php

 // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

echo 'sumbit successful';

$sessionname = (isset($_POST['Assessmentnew'])) ? $_POST['Assessmentnew'] : ''; 
$sessiondate = (isset($_POST['Datenew'])) ? $_POST['Datenew'] : ''; 
$sessiontime = (isset($_POST['Timenew'])) ? $_POST['Timenew'] : ''; 

$formatdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($sessiondate));
$formattime = date("H:i:s",strtotime($sessiontime));

$updatesql = "UPDATE Session SET SessionDate = ?, SessionTime = ? WHERE SessionName = ?";                                           
$update = $mysqli->prepare($updatesql);
$update->bind_param("sss", $formatdate, $formattime, $sessionname);
$update->execute();

echo 'update successful';

$query = "SELECT SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime FROM Session WHERE SessionName = ?";
// prepare query
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$stmt->bind_param("s", $sessionname);
// execute query
$stmt->execute(); 
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$stmt->bind_result($dbSessionName, $dbSessionDate, $dbSessionTime);
//get number of rows
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows();

echo 'select successful';

if ($numrows == 1){

echo "<span style='color: green'>Your Assessment's new Date and Time have been updated</span>";

}else{

echo "<span style='color: red'>An error has occured, your Assessment's new Date and Time have not been updated</span>";

}

        ?>
```

Comment: @VIDesignz What happens is that when I click "OK" in the confirmation, it displays the message while the page is submitting (you can see the page loading on the browser tab), when the page is submitted to itself, then it is disappeared. I have included semi colon btw, no change

Comment: @VIDesignz That maybe where the problem lies. I am simply trying to retrieve the echo from `updatedatetime.php` and place it in the `targetdiv` div tag by running this `$("#targetdiv").html(data);`. If `#targetdiv` needs to be set on page load, then that is where I am going wrong, what should it be set to?

Comment: @VIDesignz tried changing data to html but still doing same thing

Comment: @VIDesignz I am not really used to using ajax, I have just been trying to follow certain examples I have found in my research and then include it in the code. If you have a better method then it will be much appreciated if you can show a much reliable and cleaner method

Comment: @VIDesignz I did not include the code for when the Submit Course and Module button is submit to try and cut down on code. Do you want me to include it? What happens is when you click on the Update Date/Start Time button, then it will display the confirmation box, if the user clicks on OK in the confirmation box, then it will submit the form (which is to its own page) but while the page is loading it displays the success echo and then when it has been submitted, the echo message disappears, the echo message should be displayed after the form has been submitted and not disappear after submit

Comment: So everything is working as far as validating the inputs and as far as the confirm box are concerned?

Comment: @VIDesignz It is ` <script type='text/javascript'>` in main code

Comment: Apparently when its a <button> element, it defaults to submitting the form, and since there was no action set in the form itself, it kept posting back to the same page....

Comment: Did you get it working like you originally wanted to? Sorry it took so long, I had no idea the button element in the form was the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to weed through your code, to perform the form submit, this is all you need for the ajax call

```
function submitupdate() {    

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/updatedatetime.php",
        data: $('#updateForm').serialize(),
        success: function(html){
            $("#targetdiv").html(html);
        }
     });        
}
```

This assumes the

```
/updatedatetime.php
```

Calculates correctly and echos either the success or failure of the update,

Here is a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/4VVxs/) to show you the minimum you need for the form itself. You don't need to put any method, or action on the form itself, just the form tags.

As far as the button to submit...you can put that anywhere, make it anything, just make sure you give it an ID and attach a click handler to it to submit the form.

Comment: Hi, I have updated code in question, I know you used `$('body').on('click', '#update', submitupdate);`. I don't know if I can use the same thing because what I am trying to do is that when the user clicks on the "Update Date/Start Time" button, then it will go through validation function (to check if there are no empty text inputs), if there is no validation, then it shows the confirmation, what last little part do I need to add in the code in order to be able to perform the submit. At moment if user clicks on submit and ok in confirmation, then message doesn't appear

Comment: @user1819709 To your above comment, see here http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/4VVxs/7/ make note of the showconfirm() function, validating the inputs inside this function. Also, instead of using documentgetelementby id, use the Jquery shorthand.

Comment: Hi, big problem, when I submit and confirm, it doesn't perform an update, or display an echo, I have updated code in question.

Comment: @user1819709 I would put echos after each step in your updatedatetime.php to make sure your php isn't breaking. First, I would put one right at the top, this will make sure you are getting a response... ie: echo 'sumbit successful'; then I would run down your php and put echos every couple steps, such as echo 'step 1 completed'; echo 'step 2 completed'

Comment: Ok I will do this and let you know what is happening

Comment: I have included update on updatedatetime.php script in my question. Nothing is echoing, is it because the ajax is incorrect, both php scripts are in the same folder and I don't think it is performing a post because in the url you see the information which should be hidden when performing a post

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the line that submits the form again in the post call and is exaclty this line `updateFormO.submit();` . With the post method you make an ajax call and in the success function you resubmit the form again.

Comment: Can I ask what the post method should look like when making the ajax call to ensure that it is correct

Comment: the post method should be like that: 
`$.post('updatedatetime.php', { 
        Assessmentnew: $("#newAssessment").val(), 
        Datenew:$("#Datenew").val(), 
        Timenew: $("#Timenew").val() }, 
        function(data) {
      $("#targetdiv").html(data);
}); `

I just saw that you can not use the serialize method to send your data to the server. The serialize method will work perfect for the get method (.get and not .post).